# Nyromodal - Viewing it on a desktop site on Mobile

Tags: css, nyromodal

My buying and selling website: www.onlinecarbooty.com isn't mobile responsive. I have set up a mobile version though which is shrunk to 480 pixel width. Anyway, the site has a feature where photos are enlarged by clicking on them. It uses a basic looking NyroModal for this. It works fine on the desktop site and on the mobile site too using a different NyroModal - NyromodalMobile.css. But when a user is viewing the desktop site on a Mobile, the enlargements are too small. I've tried by setting up NyroMadalMobile2.css which the site uses if it detects a mobile user on the desktop site but I'm unsure what to change to display nice fitting enlargements.. I'm only just learning the programming, I have a professional who does most things for me but has lots on with other sites at the moment. If anyone can help me adjust the css file below to make the enlarged pics look better on a mobile I would so appreciate it. You can see what I'm talking about if you click a sellers item for sale on this page.. http://www.onlinecarbooty.com/go-booting.aspx

Regards, Mark

```
.nyroModalBg {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.nmReposition {
    position: absolute;
}

.nyroModalCloseButton {
    top: -13px;
    right: -13px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    background: url(img/close.gif);
}

.nyroModalTitle {
    bottom: -31px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #ffff00; width: 960px;
 }

.nyroModalCont {
    position: absolute;
    border: 4px solid #777;
    margin: 25px;
    background: #fff;
}

.nyroModalCont iframe {
    width: 960px;
    height: 800px;
}

.nyroModalError {
    border: 4px solid red;
    color: red;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}

.nyroModalError div {
    min-width: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.nyroModalLink, 
.nyroModalDom, 
.nyroModalForm, 
.nyroModalFormFile {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 960px;
    min-width: 960px;
    max-width: 960px;
}

.nyroModalImage, 
.nyroModalSwf, 
.nyroModalIframe, 
.nyroModalIframeForm {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nyroModalImage img {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.nyroModalHidden {
    left: -9999em;
    top: -9999em;
}

.nyroModalLoad {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #fff url(img/ajaxLoader.gif) no-repeat center;
    padding: 0;
}

.nyroModalPrev, 
.nyroModalNext {
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 60%;
    width: 150px;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    background: transparent url('data:image/gif;base64,AAAA') left 50% no-repeat;
}

.nyroModalImage 
.nyroModalPrev, 
.nyroModalImage 
.nyroModalNext {
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    max-height: none;
}

.nyroModalPrev {
    left: 0; background-image: url(img/prevmob.png);
}

.nyroModalPrev:hover{}
.nyroModalNext {
    right: 0;
    background-position: right 50%; background-image: url(img/nextmob.png);
}

.nyroModalNext:hover{}
```